# Transient info dialog on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

**Scenario:**

1. An iOS app has a list of cars
2. User clicks a car in the list and an "edit car" page is displayed
3. User modifies data and clicks OK and is returned to the list
4. At this point we would like to display a transient informational message to
   the use. A message that disappear after a few seconds.

What is the iOS way of showing transient messages like you would in Android toast?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Rasmus. At the moment, this question is a bit broad to answer. Can you clarify what you mean by "doing that"? What, in particular are you trying to determine about the message? (Its format? Its duration of appearance? Its method of dismissal? Its position? Its wording? Something else?)

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for an iOS alternative to an Android toast  message.  I'm going to edit the question along those lines, but if it was not your intention, please correct the edit and improve the question yourself.

Comment: Super input JohnGB, I just didn't know that it was called a toast message

Answer (score 1):

There is no native ios support for something like toast that I am aware of. According to ios Human Interface guidelines the standard convention for addressing temporary messages would be to use the UI Alert. The guidelines go on to suggest the following:

> If the alert does this... Informs users of problems they can do nothing about: If the problem isn’t critical, integrate the information into the app’s UI; otherwise, use an alert.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html

It's my understanding that a UI Alert could be displayed using a pop animation and be automatically dismissed via timeout, to achieve something like toast.

If you require something that looks and behaves a bit more like toast there are a myriad of custom controls you can integrate to achieve the same effect on ios. Here is one for example:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/altoastview

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the user experience guide. And to the array of cocoa controls.

Answer (score 0):

The top message slider that slides down from the top of the screen. On my iPhone6 I see it both with the controls and just with the info (texts, im messages etc). It slides back up in a few seconds unless reacted to.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. As JohnGB pointed out I was looking for a toast message

Comment: But I would not abuse it for in-app messages. They distract from the user workflow, and the user is used to having these messages refer to _other_ apps, not the one they are currently in.